# Strange exception when implementing interface

Tags: java

I have `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A (wrong name: a)` and I dont't have any idea what this can caused by

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new B();
    }
}

interface a { }

class A implements a { }

class B extends A { }
```

Edit: in online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler it compiles

Comment: Is this all one file? Interfaces and classes should be capitalized, anyway

Comment: yes, named Test.java

Comment: And what are you using to run the file?

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: IntelliJ Idea IDE

Comment: Java version  11.0.4

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this Windows?

Comment: Yes, it is Windows

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When Java compiles your source code, it creates multiple `.class` files. For example, it creates `Test.class` for `public class Test`, `a.class` for `interface a`, and `A.class` for `class A`. The problem here is that file names in some operating systems are case-insensitive. This means that the operating system sees `a.class` and `A.class` as the same file so one will overwrite the other.

The online compiler most likely treats these file names as different due to case-sensitivity.

The solution here is to use different names so that you avoid these name collisions at the operating system level.

The established Java convention is to start all class and interface names with an upper case letter. If you follow this convention, then you will avoid this problem.

Comment: In addition, type names in Java should always be Capitalized.

Comment: "Test$a.class for interface a" why? `a` is not nested type.

Comment: @Pshemo I was thinking that the Java compiler would generate class files with the $ syntax for private classes. I'm probably mistaken in that detail. The underlying problem is still how the OS deals with case differences in file names.

Comment: "So for private classes Java won't create a file with the $ syntax" well, private classes can only exist *within* other classes (are nested) so they will be in form `OuterClass$InnerClass` but here classes are not private, they don't have have specified access modifiers so they are *package-private* - they belong to entire package (its access is allowed only to elements from same package).

Comment: @Pshemo So what will be the names of the generated class files?

Comment: Now names of `.class` files in your answer seem correct. Anyway main problem is correctly described in your answer (although it is strange that when I execute in console `javac Text.java` I will get `B.class` `a.class` and `Test.class` but compiler will not inform me about problem with `A.class`).

Comment: @Pshemo The compiler doesn't complain because it treats the class names as case sensitive. Of course, the compiler writes should know enough about Windows that this is a problem and could easily warn us.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `javac` `path/to/your/file`, you should see the list of `.class`files created by the java compiler in that dir. The problem with your approach is you have duplicate names for the interface and the class i.e A (case insensitive) and as a result only one `.class` gets created. Try again by changing the name of either interface or class and your problem should go away.